# java.io.IOException: Port not bound (found port -1). Is there an enabled firewall?

Tags: eclipse, aptana, pydev, aptana3

Whenever i try for auto-complete for modules,properties,variables etc with Ctrl+Space I'm getting following error in auto-completion helper window. And I see editor showing few imported modules,properties,variables etc with red underlined saying "Undefined variable".

How to fix this issue?

**java.io.IOException: Port not bound (found port -1). Is there an enabled firewall?**

OS: Fedora 20 with Firewall service enabled

Editor: Aptana Studio 3.6.0 (Eclipse Platform: 4.3.2)

Plugin: PyDev 3.0.0

Comment: Maybe you have to let Aptana do something that the firewall is preventing it from doing?

Comment: also see [this](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-WhenIdoacodecompletion%2CPyDevhangs%2CwhatcanIdo%3F)

Answer (score -1):

..try downloading a fresh/new copy of eclipse, install the pydev 3.0.0 plugin and re-test..if same error then disable fw: systemctl stop firewalld

if you are using iptables instead then simply (for now) flush all the rules: iptables -F

..and re-test.  i was not aware that PyDev required a certain port to operate.

Answer (score -1):

can you try to re-install Aptana (with a latest version)? Note that it will uninstall pydev when upgrading new Aptana. Then you can re-install pydev.